# I'm looking for a book series about a Queen that time travels to save her people

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, technology

I'm looking for a book series about a Queen that time travels to save her people. What I remember from the books was a girl that lived in the "highlands" came down to a festival where she was taking a bird, a falcon or a hawk, she had trained for a competition. The ruling king didn't want to be beat, so he killed her bird and when she complained he threw her in a jail/dungeon.

Somehow she breaks free and a rebellion of some sort tries to start. There is a part about a "wizard" or what everyone thinks/calls a wizard who ends up being some kind of time traveler that has a portal in a wall high up in the mountain, and he lives a really long time and has been searching for this girl, and the "magic" is really technology and it is a computer set in a wall. This wizard somehow gets with the bird girl and he tells her he is going to help her and she is a queen and she isn't sure she wants to be, and she ends up in love with some guy, but because she travels to different points of time that are crucial battles in time to help rally her people, it doesn't seem to work out if I remember right.

There is also something I remember about a sword she is given that is part of how people know she is "their legend queen" that she has when she is young and old when she appears, and there are portals of some kind.

I also vaguely remember something about smaller villages of "highland and lowland" type origins that are clans that come together and have a competition to see who's fastest/strongest etc, where some guy throws a large stone, and there is some guy that was part of the clan or is part of the clan that lives apart in this hut in the woods.

I also remember a waterfall emptying into a pool or something like that.

I think the title of the first book had the word red and maybe stag or hawk and maybe queen, but googling those has come up with no results.

I think it was two or three books in total, but I could be wrong. I'd like to read them again, but I just can't remember a title or author or much else about them. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like *[Ironhand's Daughter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/568104.Ironhand_s_Daughter)* by David Gemmell. It's part of the Hawk Queen duology.

1. *Ironhand's Daughter* (1995)
2. *The Hawk Eternal* (1995)

> The armies of the Outlanders crushed the highlanders at the battle of Colden Moor–killing their finest warriors and breaking their freeborn spirit. The highlanders are now a conquered people, ruled by the brutal Baron Gottasson.
>   Prophecies speak of the coming of a new leader, a descendent of Ironhand, mightiest of the highland kings. A leader who will throw off the Outlander yoke. But only one highlander carries the blood of Ironhand: Sigarni, a wild and willful teenage girl who cares for nothing save her own concerns. Until a fateful encounter thrusts her onto a path of rebellion. Now, hunted by the baron’s soldiers and stalked by an evil sorcerer, Sigarni will be forced to fulfill her destiny . . . or perish.